# Powershell: export-csv, exclude certain data from tables

Tags: powershell, csv

i created a very small script to get certain information of SQL Server databases, this information will be passed on to another script.

It bassicaly gets the name, and collation of the existings databases on the server, and writes the value's to a CSV file. The code is working, though I want to exclude the system databases from the file. Can anyone help me out achieving this, i am fairly new to Powershell, so please bear with me.

Code:

```
  param (
[parameter(mandatory=$true)] [string] $servername
)

[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO') | out-null
$s = New-Object ('Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server') $servername
$dbs=$s.databases
$dbs | select name, collation | export-csv C:\tmp\dbs.csv
```

CSV Output:

```
DB1,"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
DB2,"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
DB3,"SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"
master,"Latin1_General_CI_AS"
model,"Latin1_General_CI_AS"
msdb,"Latin1_General_CI_AS"
tempdb,"Latin1_General_CI_AS"
```

The ones i want excluded from the CSV file are the master, model, msdb and tempdb databases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace your last line with:

```
$dbs | ?{ @("master", "model", "msdb", "tempdb")  -notcontains $_.Name } | select name, collation | export-csv C:\tmp\dbs.csv
```